# Event declaration which fix my tests

Tags: truffle-test, solidity-0.5.x

I'm going to try to put this in simple. This is the code of my contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Lottery {
    address public manager;
    address[] public players;
    event Deposit(address _from, uint value);

    constructor() public {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        require(msg.value > .01 ether, 'Not enough ether');
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function numberPlayers() public view returns(uint) {
        return players.length;
    }
}
```

And this is the code of my test:

```js
const lottery = artifacts.require('Lottery');

contract('Lottery', accounts => {
    let instance;

    beforeEach( async () => {
        instance = await lottery.deployed();
    });

    it('should have as manager the account which deployed', async () => {
        const manager = await instance.manager.call();

        assert.equal(manager, accounts[0]);
    });

    it('should create a player if the player send some ether', async () => {
        const payment = web3.utils.toWei("0.02", "ether");
        await instance.enter.sendTransaction({from: accounts[1], value: payment});
        const numberPlayers = await instance.numberPlayers.call();
        const player = await instance.players(numberPlayers - 1);

        assert.equal(player, accounts[1]);
    })
});
```

Everything works fine but if I comment the *Deposit* event in the line 6 like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Lottery {
    address public manager;
    address[] public players;
    // event Deposit(address _from, uint value);

    constructor() public {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        require(msg.value > .01 ether, 'Not enough ether');
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function numberPlayers() public view returns(uint) {
        return players.length;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the next error:

```
1) Contract: Lottery
       should create a player if the player send some ether:
     Error: Invalid number of parameters for "enter". Got 1 expected 2!
      at Object.InvalidNumberOfParams (/Users/adrian.ferrereses/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth-contract/~/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:32:1)
      at Object._createTxObject (/Users/adrian.ferrereses/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:699:1)
      at constructor.detectNetwork.then.network (/Users/adrian.ferrereses/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-contract/lib/execute.js:170:1)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I'm pretty new in solidity, so I do not know if I'm doing something wrong or if I've encountered an error in version 0.5 of the solidity compiler.

These are the versions of my environment:

```
Truffle v5.0.15 (core: 5.0.15)
Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js)
Node v10.15.3
Web3.js v1.0.0-beta.37
```

If you want to test this issue by your self, you can download the code from this repository:
https://github.com/ardiadrianadri/lotter-project

Thank you very much everyone for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented out the `Deposit` event and ran `truffle test --network develop`.
It came out fine:

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol
> Compiling ./contracts/lottery.sol
> Artifacts written to /var/folders/ch/c9xd4bp91c5blg80llj8ytvc0000gn/T/test-119416-6547-11frumz.via4
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.0+commit.1d4f565a.Emscripten.clang



  Contract: Lottery
    ✓ should have as manager the account which deployed
    ✓ should create a player if the player send some ether (92ms)


  2 passing (143ms)
```

It is most probably some weird Truffle quirk - they happen really often. Please, try removing your `build` directory and running tests again.

Comment: Thank you Ivan Andrusenko. I removed the build directory and everything went fine.